# EOFException: null Observed while changing log level of ROOT to Debug dynamically on RunTime using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am on my learning path using SpringBoot & Actuator I have tried to modify the log level during run time.

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/ROOT
```

I was able to change log level of all classes without any error, but when I tried to change log level of `ROOT` to `DEBUG`, I am getting this Debug message on the console window. Please help with this issue. Thank you.

```
01:05:03.635 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1331)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1218)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:805)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
01:05:03.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@6ecb5498:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@74d10d9c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53630]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
01:05:03.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@78a7bf9d]
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am seeing the same at debug level. This message seems harmless to the API as the API is working well
Is this a false alarm which apache tomcat should fix or should something be fixed in the project for teh case to not happen?

Comment: @user2512997 no it is a harmless logs and i had 2 ways of changing log level one using spring-boot acctuator's loggers  another one is i had written a rest endpoint that makes use of LoggerContext and i would set loglevel using ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger lLogger  object